# Convert the string to an object

Tags: javascript, json, string

I want to convert a string to an object.

My string is something like `7541550448872:1:1:monthly,42397357179112:1`.

I want the result to be something like this:

```js
'items': [{
    'id': 7541550448872,
    'quantity': 1,
    "properties": {
      "shipping_interval_unit_type": "monthly",
      "shipping_interval_frequency": "1"
    },
  },
  {
    'id': 42397357179112,
    'quantity': 1,
  }
]
```

I was told to use functions like `split()` and `Regex` but I could not get it to work. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. You need to first make an attempt at it and if/where you have problems, we will attempt to help you

Comment: This can be done dynamically however i wonder why exactly you end up with a string like that in the first place? Perhaps you should consider structuring your code to be helpful at later stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, probably the most preferred method is using `Array.split()`. You split the array by `:`, and then construct the JSON by indexing the array. See the code snippet below to see this in action. Also, I'm not sure if you wanted a `,` between the month and the `id` or if was just a typo. My code below uses the `,`.

```js
const str = '7541550448872:1:1:monthly,42397357179112:1';
const arr = str.split(':');
const json = {
  'items': [{
      'id': Number(arr[0]),
      'quantity': Number(arr[1]),
      "properties": {
        "shipping_interval_unit_type": arr[3].split(',')[0],
        "shipping_interval_frequency": arr[2]
      },
    },
    {
      'id': Number(arr[3].split(',')[1]),
      'quantity': Number(arr[4]),
    }
  ]
};

console.log(json);
```

**Hoped this helped!**